# Creating a custom Jackson Property Naming Strategy

Tags: json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

Many of the external APIs I am calling return object fields in this format “FIRST_NAME”. However I want to send them out in camel case “firstName”

Without marking each and every object I have as:

```
private String firstName;

@JsonGetter(“firstName”)
public String getFirstName(){
     returns firstName;
}

@JsonSetter(“FIRST_NAME”)
public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
{
this.firstName=firstName;
}
```

I tried creating a custom PropertyNamingStartegy but was not able to get it to work. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

From the typo in your code `returns`, I can see this code is typed by hand.

Actually your solution where different name on `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonSetter` should work. Maybe you have Jackson customization which prevents it from working. I hardly can tell why without seeing your full code. Anyway, I will given you another solution.

[@JsonAlias](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) defines alternative name during deserialization. The original name ("firstName" in your example) still works.

Either put on field

```java
@JsonAlias("FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;
```

or on `@JsonSetter` method

```java
private String firstName;

@JsonGetter("firstName")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

@JsonSetter
@JsonAlias("FIRST_NAME")
void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

The full test code in on [Github](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/spring-boot-study/commit/9a03d56213605c3b72810ebc4b190d7e79ea9784). If still not work, either fork my repository and change to your class and test, or share a ready-to-run project on Github to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah sorry, typed it from my phone :). Thanks! That works as well. I was actually able to make a custom object mapper and property naming strategy last night that allows me to handle it. I have many fields and classes so I was looking to reduce the annotations if possible.